# PrestaShop force customer to choose product attribute

Tags: javascript, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm creating  a PrestaShop shop online and currently I'm struggling with forcing customer to pick the attribute for his product before adding to cart. Attributes like color and size.

For now, customer can order product with default attributes set by me and I don't want it to be possible.

I didn't see such an option in the settings so I tried to add custom JS lines to PrestaShop **theme.js**.

The "**add to cart**" button on default is **grey** and has no **pointer-events**. ( I changed that in **theme.css** ).

When you pick an attribute, it works for a milisecond. ( The button is now **blue** and has **pointer-events** ).

Then suddenly page refreshes or something. I don't know extacly what's happening. The URL changes and the button is **grey** and has no **pointer-events** again.

Has anyone struggled with this issue when creating a store on PrestaShop or knows how I could achieve my goal?

PrestaShop 1.7 version

My custom JS below:

```
let addToCartActive = false;
const btnPrimary = document.querySelector(".btn-primary");


const formControlSelect = document.querySelector(".form-control-select");
 formControlSelect.addEventListener("change", function () {
if (addToCartActive == false) {
    addToCartActive = true;
    btnPrimary.style.backgroundColor = "#24b9d7";
    btnPrimary.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
} else {
    btnPrimary.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    btnPrimary.style.pointerEvents = "none";
}
});
```

Comment: if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, for just about 50€ there are several modules available that do this in official Addons, search for "force attribute".

Comment: Unfortunately buying a module is not an option...